# Share a folder between Heroku App

Tags: heroku

For my project, I would like to be able to setup multiple websites (App) and according to the requirements from a clients, I will activate and setup modules. Those modules could be a news module, images viewer module and so on.

My engine, which consist of scripts and libraries that manage a few things such as the WebApp routing, the modules, user rights for the CMS. I would like to get this code shared among all my App to avoid unseless duplication.

I would like to know what's the best way to do this on Heroku since I am totally new to this (Heroku) and I am not totally sure if that is feasable.

Also, am I wrong to believe that each websites is an App even if basically the only difference between them are the template and a single setup file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have no experience with git get familiar with it.
2. I would suggest to have one application with different branches in which you keep the configuration specific to the instance.
3. You create an app instance for each website.
4. You push the specific branch to the specific app, e.g.

   git push git@heroku.com:.git :master

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly: The 2 is on my local machine. I have a branch for every websites on my own prod that I push to a dev new app on heroku. Is that it?

Comment: Another way I could do it is to have one (1) App with multiple domains pointing to it so I can load the good setting file depending of the request server name. Is that, a good idea?

Comment: @Cybrix comment 2: I am not sure if this is such a great idea as it needs some development work which might be tricky and if something goes wrong, all websites might be down. In my proposal you can mess up only one a time. So, in the end a matter of taste:-)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. So, do you suggest me to push my "application logic" along with the website for each of them? If I want to avoid that, what would be the way to do it?

Comment: To follow up with my previous comment. I am not sure if I want to duplicate some part of my codes. It will most likely be modified alot to eventually become a good final product and I do not want to duplicate the changes for all the websites.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the nature of your project. I agree duplication of code is the worst but that's not what I indented - you can have on master containing all code and branches with different configuration files. Every time you change the master you merge it into all branches. Configuration doesn't change, code is maintained in one branch. Cool in my humble project, but maybe not the approbate approach. To help on this much clearer requirements are needed but this might be not the place to discuss such issues.